# Printing words with capital letters in Perl using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I tried to make an algorithm in Perl to print only words with only the first letter being a capital letter. For the example:

```
Hey
now
Brown cow
```

It should print:

```
Hey
Brown
```

But it is printing:

```
Hey
Brown cow
```

Here is my code:

```
while (<>) {
    if (/^[A-Z][a-z]+/) {
        print;
    }
}

print "\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently printing lines that begin with a capital word.

To print words, you'll need to adjust your regex to either capture words:

```
while (<>) {
    while (/\b([A-Z][a-z]+)/g) {
        print $1, "\n";
    }
}
```

Or separate words to begin with and then filter out the capital ones:

```
while (<>) {
    for (grep /^[A-Z]/, split) {
        print $_, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thks!! It worked. I had tried `/\b([A-Z][a-z]+)/`, without the 'g' at the end, but it hadn't worked.

Comment: Let's say I have:
`Hey`
`now`
`Brown Cow`
How do I do so that the output is:
`Hey`
`Brown`
This means, it prints only the words with the first letter being cpaital and only one word that matches the rules per line?

Comment: For the first solution, we'd change the while to an if:  `if (/\b([A-Z][a-z]+)/) {`.  For the second solution, we'd change the for to an if: `if (my ($match) = grep /^[A-Z]/, split) { print "$match\n" }`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
while ( /\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b/g ) { print $1 . $/; }
```

Starting from the beginning of a word boundary (`\b`), we require at exactly one uppercase letter (`[A-Z]`).  To finish off the word, we allow any number of lowercase letters (`[a-z]*`) until we reach the end of word (`\b`).

[Here's a working example.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2a%29%5Cb&input=Hey%0Anow%0ABrown%20cow%0ADOESNTWORK%0Adoesn%27t%20work%0ANumb3rs%0AWorks)

Comment: Ah, I missed the "only the first letter".  Fixed the answer.

Comment: dont be greedy `*` :)

Comment: @Paulchenkiller Being greedy is fine here.  Non-greedy is needed when one is relying more on a boundary condition instead of limiting what is allowed to match using a character class.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not lying to you. It matches a capitalized word, but then you go ahead and print the whole line.

If you want to print only words that match, then the following should work:

```
my @words;
while (<>) {
    @words = split(/\s+/);
    foreach my $word (@words) {
        print if (/^[A-Z][a-z]+/);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex suggests capital words at the beginning of the line. It also suggests you don't consider `I` a word. Given the characters you are interested in, you could fix that using -

`/^[A-Z](?i:[a-z])*/m and print $&,"\n";`

I put the multi-line modifier in because I can't tell what you're using for a line delimiter.